# Kernel module on cross-compile kernel: /bin/sh: 1: scripts/basic/fixdep: Exec format error

Tags: linux, kernel-module

I'm doing some experiment on rpi4, and trying to reproduce this kernel module from github https://github.com/sysprog21/dont-trace on my rpi4. I encounter this problem:

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=/home/ubuntu/dont-trace modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.65-rt49-preemptrt-full-raspi'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
  CC [M]  /home/ubuntu/dont-trace/dont_trace.o
/bin/sh: 1: scripts/basic/fixdep: Exec format error
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:289: /home/ubuntu/dont-trace/dont_trace.o] Error 126
make[2]: *** Deleting file '/home/ubuntu/dont-trace/dont_trace.o'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1896: /home/ubuntu/dont-trace] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.65-rt49-preemptrt-full-raspi'
make: *** [Makefile:7: all] Error 2
```

The kernel here is cross-compiled from x86 server and do show above. I was wondering how to solve this problem & what's the root cause. I can make it on x86 server. It should be something fundamental knowledge I don't understand. Thks!

Comment: You will need to override `ARCH` and `CROSS_COMPILE` when calling `make`, something like this: `make -C /lib/modules/\`uname -r\`/build ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- M=/home/ubuntu/dont-trace modules`. You may need to install a suitable toolchain first: `sudo apt install crossbuild-essential-arm64`. The gcc version is still likely to be different from the one used to build the kernel, but at least it will be building for the correct architecture.

Comment: Thk for your comment, @lan Abbott. Sorry for my poor description, my case is: I have an cross-compile kernel for raspberry pi on x86 server (`make deb-pkg`). And I was trying compile kernel module on rpi, but it problem occurs. The environment is arm64 already, and gcc (for arm64), many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems work this time

My solution might be a bit workaround, but it works. I follow the clues `/bin/sh: 1: scripts/basic/fixdep: Exec format error`. So I copy the source code to local raspberry pi, and `make modules_prepare` to construct complete `/scripts`, then move it into `` /lib/modules/`uname -r\`/build ``. It remain the gcc version warning, but work properly.